# Get the filename that the record come from

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, grep

I have a huge number of `.gz` files, which being uncompressed using `zcat` together.

I am looking to get from where each record came from, as below example:

File1:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,NEW,9,10,11,12
13,14,15,55,884,66873,156,8
```

Using below code for file1 to file10000:

```
zcat file.gz* | grep "NEW"
```

The desired output should look like:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,NEW,9,10,11,12 > file1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to pipe `zcat` to `grep`, simply use `zgrep`:

```
zgrep NEW *.gz
```

By default, when called over multiple files it prints the name of the file where the match is found. (It won't be exactly like your desired output, but based on your question it should fit your needs.)

Answer (score 2):

Just add `-H` flag to your `zgrep` command:

```
zgrep -H "ERROR" *.gz
```